Regularization / Smoothing of a nonsmooth function
I want to regularize a function such that $G_{\epsilon}(x) = 1$ for $|x| > \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is small, and $G_{\epsilon}(0) = 0$, so that $G_{\epsilon}$ converges uniformly towards 1.
The function I tried is the following:
$$
F_{\epsilon}(x) = \left|\tanh\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)\right|
$$
but even after trying to regularize the absolute value function using $x \tanh\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)$, I am not able to get a good approximation for $G_{\epsilon}$.

How about some thing like $ 1-\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ where is the standard mollifier function?

As @totaldependentrandomchoice note in his comment, you could try by scalling some smooth bump function and subtracted from one.
As example, you could use some argument $f(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ for the following function with $k>0$:
$$f(x,k) = \begin{cases} 1,\quad x\leq -1;\\
1,\quad x\geq 1;\\
0,\quad x=0;\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{-k(1-2|x|)}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\quad\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$
You could check it in Desmos. Note that $f(x)$ is smooth class $C^\infty$, but is not analytic in $x=\{-1,\ 0,\ 1\}$. Also in this case, if you use $k<0$, you will recover the smooth bump function from here.

